# Starting a UI/UX design career

Tags: ux-designer, education

I currently studying graphic design at school, but it looks like I am not going better, so I have to jump into UI/UX design to start learning on my own, but I have no idea about this technology, I don’t know when to start or what should have first to begin, I only master Photoshop & Illustrator, I think that’s not enough to be a good UI designer.

So my questions is as follows: **Can I learn UI/UX Design on my own without going to school?** If yes,
Where I can find courses, YouTube, Lynda or only trough eBooks?
My aim is to work with clients and large companies around the world or even be a part of a talented team of UX designers, so please help me to find the right path into the goal, you have knowledge, experience, free resources or even a good idea, just share and help me achieve my dream.
Thank you so much guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is selling career advise. SE is not organized to offer such advice. The chat section, or more discussion driven forum, would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If this was about programming self studies asked on Stack Overflow, OP would be redirected to Programmers.SE, wouldn't they? But since UX.SE does not have a sister site like that, I would allow it here.

Comment: Searching on here for a question on good UX books -will find a question on good UX books :-)

Comment: Yes, but this question is also about if those books would get you educated like a attending a school would.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey, I was thinking the same, but then I didn't see an option in the flagging wizard about career advice being off topic. (This question might be overly broad, though.)

Comment: What research have you done regarding this?

Comment: I would ask your local chapter of UXPA for pointers to courses etc in your region http://uxpa.org/chapters-sigs-by-region

Answer (score 1):

### Do $1 jobs.

Carefully select businesses and organisations you know your current design abilities can assist.

Approach them, pitch a plan, and timelines, plus estimate the cost of adopting your ideas and output. Contrast this with the benefits you predict it'll accrue for the business or organisation. Initially you'll be off on these costs, but whoever you target will happily correct you, for free.

Not everyone is going to be able to justify the extraneous costs of your proposed changes. Your fee of $1 is not the total cost of adoption and implementation. But the $1 fee does create enough acknowledgement of your activities as a service that you won't often be exploited.

*Be sure to make it clear your fee is $1, flat. This, believe it or not, indicates you're serious and understand the value of a contract. Doing work for free doesn't quite have this level of obligation, but a single dollar goes a long way to making things much more official, on both sides.*

This requires a self awareness and assessment of your reach, influence, abilities and reverence. Which will all improve as you do this.This will be all the education you need. It will force you to self educate, practice, do, demonstrate, integrate and be a designer.

Throughout your career, never stop doing this.

After a remarkably short time of doing this, people will hear about what you're doing, see what you've done, and begin propositioning you. In these circumstances, everything changes. The $1 contract is gone, and you begin to sharpen your negotiation skills. Those that approach you are going to make an offer. You must counter their initial offer, and reach an agreement.

And now you're a freelancer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say self studies is a possible path towards landing a UX job.

I have a CS degree with only a minor ingredient of UX courses in it. But I still dare to say that skills in our business springs more from interest, will, talent, and ambition, or even obsession, than it does from physical resources and formal degrees.

You would not be able to self study at home to get a job as a doctor, an architect or a pilot. But just a computer with internet at home gets you a long way to a job about computers and internet.

The only missing part compared to a school is people. Teachers, mentors, peers, group assignments, coaching, feedback, examination. For seeking all this out yourself, you cannot afford to lack in dedication. Here are just a few ideas:

- [**Books**] Starting with literature, many universities has course material listed online. Have a look around major universities websites, ([MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=engineering&subcat=computerscience&spec=humancomputerinterfaces) is one with publicly available material, but there are many more). It may be a big task to find a great list of study literature without guidance, but there are also many lists compiled for you on the web. Here's one: [medium.com/interactive-mind/the-only-ux-reading-list-ever](https://medium.com/interactive-mind/the-only-ux-reading-list-ever-d420edb3f4ff#.7iszd3my9).
- [**Mentorship, Coaching**] Perhaps you could enroll in a mentorship program at your school or find a traineeship at a company? As long as you show ambition and stamina, you will sooner or later find a company that will let you work for a minor compensation or for free, for you to get some experience in return.
- [**Peers, discussions**] Depending on where you live, there are groups of people coming
  together to talk about trends and challenges, for example [Product
  Tank](http://www.producttank.com/) or [UXPA](http://uxpa.org/chapters-sigs-by-region) where you might be able to find peers and ask questions.
- [**Group work, Feedback**] I don't know if you are a programmer, but if you are not already taking
  a UX role in any Open Source project out there, [YourFirstPr](https://yourfirstpr.github.io/) is a
  great place to start. To land a job without a degree, you must prove your ability to get things done in other ways. Open Source contribution is one way.